# Returning a const variable - can it cause problems?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm new to C++, haven't found an answer to this because the search results are always about the function signature and not this.

Basically, if I have a function:

```
std::string MyFunction(const int test) const
{
    const std::string str1 = "Hello";
    const std::string str2 = "World";
    return test > 7 ? str1 : str2;
}
```

The return value is either `str1` or `str2`, which are both `const`. Can this cause problems for the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The return value is either `str1` or `str2`, which are both `const`. Can this cause problems for the caller?

No, it won't. The returned object is a copy of one of those.

As an aside, the use of `const` in the argument type is pointless in most use cases. Whether you modify the value of the argument in the function or not does not impact the calling function. Unless you have a strong reason to justify use of `const`, I recommend using the simpler form without the `const`.

```
std::string MyFunction(int test) const { ... }
```

Comment: "the use of `const` in the argument type is pointless." I strongly disagree. The use of `const` in an argument type for a function *declaration* is pointless, but in a *definition*, it has almost as much point as marking a variable `const`

Comment: The use of the `const` argument type is as pointless (or not) as declaring `str1` and `str2` to be `const` (given that we have a function definition.)

Comment: `const int` isn't pointless. It's a way of telling the compiler "I promise I will not change this value" and from there all sorts of optimizations are possible.

Comment: @tadman: It isn't pointless, but optimizations do not happen because of `const`.

Comment: const on a function argument can also help avoid implementation errors. for example, say you have something like: bool MyFunction(uint16_t const count, ObjType const ** instances); marking count const will prevent you from accidentally changing it in the function body. I agree it doesn't matter to the caller and most of the time you aren't going to screw up something like that but it also hurts nothing to have in place.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, The comments from everybody was an educational experience for me. It's good to hear different perspectives on a coding style.

Answer (score 3):

The type you are returning is `std::string`, not `const std::string`. The caller shouldn't care what the type of the local variables is (the caller may not even have access to the definition/body/implementation of the function!).

In general, the types of local variables in the body of a function cannot change the return type of the function itself (`auto` and lambdas excluded).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OP seemed concerned about creating a `const` object and then returning it as non-`const`. What I meant to tell him/her is that, as long as he/she wrote `std::string` as the return type, there was nothing the function could do regarding that in its implementation.

Comment: @Deduplicator OP's concern seemed to me to be that they think they may be allowing the user to modify a `const std::string`, as if the return type was `std::string &` where the compiler is allowing an implicit `const` cast. It's a common concern for users coming from languages like Java.

Comment: @Acorn yes, you understood me correctly, and your answer did help me, but the explicit "No, it won't" in the other answer wins. Thanks!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think OP's concern was about the common misconception that the "constness" of the object is somehow "carried over" to the caller because it was created as `const`, possibly because he/she thinks that the object returned is not a copy. Therefore, in that frame of thought, one could be concerned that you are introducing undefined behavior (think about it the same way as clearing the constness of a `const` object with `const_cast`).

Comment: @Acorn Ah, got it. Hadn't concidered it like that.